# Tailwind's @apply directive works in frontend but not on backend with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, tailwind-css

I have an Angular 2 app, version 9.1, that uses Angular Universal's server side rendering capabilities to deliver our pages. The app also uses the Tailwind CSS framework. We use the `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` builder for build architect and `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server` for serve architect in order to support Tailwind.

For the Tailwind installation, we simply add a rule to Webpack that gets merged into the end of Angular's own Webpack definition. Listed below is the rule that we add.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        syntax: 'postcss-scss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-import'),
          require('tailwindcss')('apps/dec-mkt/tailwind.config.js'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
          purgecss
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The app works as we would expect for the most part. Tailwind's purgecss features work great and everything eventually renders properly but there is one important feature of Tailwind that we cannot seem to leverage properly. The (@apply feature)[https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components] works but only gets computed on the frontend after the browser renders the page. As an example of this, here is a snippet of the CSS that gets delivered from the ssr server to the browser in the document .

```
<style ng-transition="serverApp">
  .menu-item[_ngcontent-sc34]{
      @apply flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center px-0 mx-2 py-3 text-base font-bold;
      max-width: 120px;
  }
</style>
```

As you can see, the @apply is not being computed at server / build time. After the app activates in the browser however, these @apply references do get properly transformed. The issue with this however is that every CSS rules that uses @apply is not styled for a second causing jumpiness. I find it strange that this would even work in the browser at all since browsers are not usually meant to do processing like this. Does anyone have any insight into how Angular's build process works that may help solve this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @Starscream I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 11.2 now fully supports tailwind by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms. Having `@apply` directives in the server side computed styles was a clear sign to me that tailwind was not being run on the server bundles.

This was quite hard to diagnose, because the main style bundle comes from the browser build and works as expected, but all styles I had in my component stylesheets weren't properly compiled.

I realised that I forgot to  update my `angular.json` server configuration. With tailwind configured via a custom webpack configuration, this was the correct configuration, effectively applying the custom webpack config to the server as well:

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
  "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./webpack.config.ts"
    }
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Please note that if you're using the native tailwind support from angular (coming in version 11.2), you don't have to do this and it'll work out of the box.